# Block for collecting samples - Simulink

Tags: serialization, signal-processing, communication, simulink, sample

Is there a way in Simulink where we can collect the samples generated during the simulation. I have a random integer generator block which generates integers between 0-15 and am mapping the integers to chip sequences as mentioned in the 802.15.4 standard. The data to chip mapper outputs a vector of 32x1 and I would like to store n such chip sequences and serialize them before OQPSK modulating the signal. Is there a block in Simulink to do this? If not an idea on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Sommer

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: you want to store the data to the (MATLAB) workspace? This is your 32x1 vector which presumable changes at each time step, so you'll end with 32xn data + a time vector. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: I have an integer generator which generates integers between 0 and 15 and these integers are mapped to corresponding 32 bit sequences. So the output of my symbol to chip mapper is a 32x1 sequence which is passed to the OQPSK modulator. I need a way to somehow store N such sequences and pass them sequentially to the modulator.

Comment: i.e., I am looking for a way to somehow buffer all the chips for the entire simulation time at once and then send the sequences through the modulator so that I get the required spectrum. Since, currently if I plot the spectrum there are overlaps of N sequences in the spectrum which is not the required one.